# as for struct , the different between * .and ->

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int compare(void const *a,void const *b);
    typedef struct {
        int key;
        char * value;
    } map;
void main()
{
    map maplist[3] = {{1,"string1"},{2,"string2"},{3,"string3"}};
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("key = %d, value = %s\n", maplist[i].key, maplist[i].value);
        //printf("key = %d\n", maplist[i]->key);
    }   
    qsort(maplist,3,sizeof(map),compare);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("key = %d, value = %s\n", maplist[i].key, maplist[i].value);
    }   
}

int compare(void const *a,void const *b) 
{
    int aa= (*(map *)a).key;
    int bb = (*(map *)b).key;
    return ((map *)a->key) - ((map *)b->key);
    //return ((*(map *)a).key - (*(map *)b).key);
    //return bb -aa;
}
```

This is correct:

```
return ((*(map *)a).key - (*(map *)b).key);
```

This is wrong:

```
return ((map *)a->key) - ((map *)b->key);
```

The error information is：

```
comparetest.c: In function ‘compare’:
comparetest.c:32:18: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
  return ((map *)a->key) - ((map *)b->key);
                  ^
comparetest.c:32:18: error: request for member ‘key’ in something not a structure or union
comparetest.c:32:36: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
  return ((map *)a->key) - ((map *)b->key);
                                    ^
comparetest.c:32:36: error: request for member ‘key’ in something not a structure or union
```

I remember, the `->` is equal to `*` with `.` in most situations.

Comment: It's wrong because the cast doesn't associate to `a`.

Comment: Please can you state your question clearly at the top with a brief description of what you are try to do?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `.` versus `->`. The code `((map *)a->key)` is wrong simply because of operator precedence. The `.` and `->` operators both have higher precedence than the cast operator `( )`. Meaning that your code is equivalent to

```
(map*) (a->key) // wrong
```

and not

```
((map*)a)->key // correct
```

The latter is what you intended.

Now as it turns out, the expression `(*(map*)a).key` is completely equivalent to `((map*)a)->key` but that's not the cause of the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs becouse you are using `->` operator on `void pointer`
First you need to retype it, than use dereference operator.

Correct:

```
return (((map *)a)->key) - (((map *)b)->key);
```

Answer (score 0):

If unsure try a step by step approach.

You know the compare function receives `const` pointers to the array's elements.

The array elements are of type `map`, so the function receives `const map*`s.

```
int compare(const void *pv1, const void *pv2)
{
  const map * pm1;
  const map * pm2;
```

`void`-pointers cannot be dereferenced by their nature, they point to void.

So assign their value to something that is typed correctly:

```
  pm1 = pv1;
  pm2 = pv2;
```

Then just use the arrow operator as usual

```
  return pm1->key - pm2->key;
}
```

The above can be shortened to:

```
int compare(const void *pv1, const void *pv2)
{
  const map * pm1 = pv1;
  const map * pm2 = pv2;

  return pm1->key - pm2->key;
}
```

which in turn can be shortened to

```
int compare(const void *pv1, const void *pv2)
{
  return ((const map *) pv1)->key - ((const map *) pv2)->key;
}
```